# PHP json_encode com valores boolean e decimais

Tags: php, json

Possuo uma função PHP que obtém dados do banco de dados e me retorna uma array com os resultados. Essa array, por padrão, possui todos os dados como tipo *string*, porém alguns campos devem ser tratados como *boolean* enquanto outros devem ser tratados como valores (dinheiro) e são do tipo *decimal*.

Posteriormente eu faço uso desses dados na página HTML para executar algumas funções ou exibição de dados. Por exemplo:

- `valor` - tipo _decimal(10,2) - Usado para exibir o valor de um produto.
- `ativo` - tipo tinyint - Usado para marcar ou não um checkbox.

A array de dados que eu obtenho são geradas através de uma consulta (SELECT) ao banco de dados, com isso o retorno vem com todos os campos em `string`. Isso "resolve" uma parte do problema, pois mantém o campo `valor` com as casas decimais. O problema começa quando eu tento a conversão, usando *flags* no `json_encode`, transformar os valores de volta para *boolean* (ou *int*), e então tenho esses 2 casos:

Caso 1: Quando utilizo `json_encode($resposta,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` a coluna `valor` perde seus decimais e é arredondada. Ex.: 9.90(string) -> 10(int)

Caso 2: Quando utilizo `json_encode($resposta,JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION )` a coluna `ativo` vem como string e com isso não consigo controlar o *checkbox*.

Existe algum modo de contornar essa situação?

Comment: Estranho acabei de testar, http://ideone.com/EPzTTv , não perdeu as casas decimais, e não coloquei parametros a mais no `json_encode`

Comment: @Miguel mas aqui você está gerando uma array manualmente, o que eu faço é uma requisição sql ao banco de dados, onde os valores iniciais retornados estão todos em string. O que resolve o caso dos valores decimais, pois mantém as casas. Porém eu necessito converter para poder utilizar os valores do tipo boolean, é nessa conversão que eu perco as casas decimais.

Comment: No "ativo" por que usar tinyint ao invés de "enum"?

Comment: @DaniloMiguel acho que isso não vai interferir no resultado, seria apenas uma mudança estrutural. Por sinal, diversas questões que li no SO inglês inclusive não recomendam enum, e sim tinyint ou bit. Como o banco já possui essa estrutura, preferi manter. Mas acho que não vem ao caso.

Comment: Tem como postar um trecho do código e um var_dump() do retorno, inclusive após o json_encode?

Comment: `abs()` ou `(bool)` na coluna `ativo` antes de mandar pro json_encode não resolveria no segundo caso? JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK está transformando suas strings em ints mas se vc transformar antes JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION não deve interferir nisso.

Comment: Celsom, veja esta possível solução, http://ideone.com/EPzTTv , aqui converte manualmente o valor para float e o ativo para int

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida consegues um exemplo mais prático de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: @Miguel mas nesse caso, se houver um json_encode depois não iria "resetar" e converter de volta para string? Pois eu pensei em usar um foreach como alternativa, mas acho que o problema está acontecendo depois, na hora de usar o json_encode. Como eu uso os dados em javascript posteriormente, essa etapa é necessária.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade algo assim, não otimizei: https://eval.in/673597

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida isso mesmo! É por ai. A única diferença é que ao invés de usar JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK eu tive que usar JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION assim me retornou valor(string) e ativo(int) como eu precisava. Uma dúvida a respeito disso.. Existe um método de mudar o campo valor ao invés do ativo? ex.:  `string($produto['valor'])`. Assim eu posso manter o id (ou outros campos de int) como int também e só o valor como string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trazendo pra cá o código que linquei nos comentários. Uma solução mais simples do que tentar coordenar as flags de [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) é tratar os valores antes de passar para a função.

Nesse caso, se `ativo` deve ser um `int`ou `bool` e `valor` deve ser uma string, só é preciso tratar o ativo e não é necessária nenhuma flag, já que na saída do seu SQL todos os valores vem como `string`:

```
$produtos = array(
    array(
        'valor'=> "1.95",
        'ativo'=> '1'
    ),
    array(
        'valor' => '9.90',
        'ativo' => '0'
    ),
);

foreach( $produtos as $produto ) {
    $produto['ativo'] = abs($produto['ativo']);
    $resposta[] = $produto;
}

echo json_encode( $resposta );
```

**Resultado:**

```
[{"valor":"1.95","ativo":1},{"valor":"9.90","ativo":0}]
```

Se precisasse converter um valor para string poderia também usar `'valor' => (string) 1.95` por exemplo.

Comment: Isso ai resolve o problema, perfeito! Mas uma dúvida.. Caso eu queira converter de int para string, ou manter apenas 1 campo como string. Digamos que eu tenha varios campos do tipo int e somente o valor do tipo string, seria mais fácil converter apenas o valor para string, porém se eu usar `(string)$produto['valor']` ao fazer o JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ele perde o tipo string, se não usar essa flag, os demais não retornam como int, e sim como string. Tem como resolver isso? Se é que eu expliquei corretamente...

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste pra demonstrar que não há dificuldde com decimais ou booleanos ao converter para o formato json.

```
<?php

$x = array(9.9, 0);

$j = json_encode($x);
?>
<script>
v = JSON.parse('<?php echo $j;?>');
//document.write(v[0]);

if (v[1]) {
    s = 'verdadeiro';
} else {
    s = 'falso';
}

document.write(s);
</script>
```

A sua pergunta não deixa claro onde e como faz as comparações de valores booleanos, mas pelos comentários parece ser com JavaScript.

Para o JavaScript o valor 1 é `true` e valor 0 é `false` quando são valores numéricos. Se for do tipo string `v = '0'`, por exemplo, `v` será tido como `true`.

Para "driblar" isso pode resolver com a função `parseInt()`.

```
<?php

$x = array(9.9, '0');

$j = json_encode($x);
?>
<script>
v = JSON.parse('<?php echo $j;?>');
//document.write(v[0]);

if (parseInt(v[1])) {
    s = 'verdadeiro';
} else {
    s = 'falso';
}

document.write(s);
</script>
```

Quanto ao valor decimal, pode vir como string do banco de dados que não fará diferença.

No entanto, para prover consistência com operações matemáticas no JavaScript, converta com a função `parseFloat()` quando necessitar fazer operações matemáticas.

```
a = '9.9';
b = 3;
document.write(parseFloat(a) + b);
```

Apenas por curiosidade, para o PHP é semelhante. Apenas muda o nome das funções. Seria `intval()` e `floatval()`.

E claro, desconsiderei a comparação que verifica o tipo da variável. 
`if (v === true) {`, por exemplo, necessita de um outro tratamento mais adequado. Mas o importante é que não precisa mexer em nada no `json_encode()` para ambos os casos.